# Erro ao abrir a platafoma V10 - Cannot perform runtime binding

Tags: vb.net

Ao executar o codigo

```
            Dim objAplConf As StdBSConfApl = New StdBSConfApl()
            Dim Plataforma As StdPlatBS = New StdPlatBS()

            objAplConf.Instancia = Instance
            objAplConf.AbvtApl = "ERP"
            objAplConf.LicVersaoMinima = "10.00"

            Plataforma.AbrePlataforma(CType(Line, EnumTipoPlataforma), objAplConf)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: me parece claro a mensagem, que algo está nulo, objAplConf por exemplo. Inspecione tudo que passa para o método `AbrePlataforma` que vais encontrar o problema

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão resolve-se com a aplicação de um `AssemblyResolver`:

```
static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string assemblyFullName;

    System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;

    const string PRIMAVERA_FOLDER = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PRIMAVERA\SG100\Apl\"; 

    assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
    assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(PRIMAVERA_FOLDER, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Que deve evocar no seu método `Main` da class `Program`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

Confirme se todas as DLL específicas do **PRIMAVERA** estão com a propriedade `Copy Local = False`.